# Prove that the origin is a unique critical point of the system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the dynamical system
$$\dot{x} = -\frac{1}{2}y(1 + x) + x(1 - 4x^2 -y^2) \quad \dot{y} = 2x(1+x) +y(1-4x^2 -y^2)$$
prove that the origin is a unique critical point

Is there a nice systematic way to do this? I keep trying to just manipulate the equations algebraically, and I am getting nowhere. I see that, in this problem, the terms $(1+x)$ and $(1-4x^2 -y^2)$ are common to both equations. Is that helpful?

Comment: One moment please. I think I have an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes,  you end up solving for the common thing in the solution and setting them equal to each other.  I have it done below

Comment: Thanks! Yes this definitely works nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0 = -\frac{1}{2}y(1 + x) + x(1 - 4x^2 -y^2) $$$$\quad 0 = 2x(1+x) +y(1-4x^2 -y^2)$$
plugging in $x=0$  you easily see that makes $y=0$,  likewise if $y=0$ you (slightly less quickly) get $x=0$
So if we have another point, they are both nonzero.  Solving for the ellipse in eqach equation we have

$$1-4x^2-y^2=\frac {\frac 1 2y(1+x)}x =\frac {-2x(1+x)}{y}$$

Clear out the fractions by multiplying both sides by $xy$ we get

$$\frac 1 2 y^2(1+x)=-2x^2(1+x)$$
so either $x+1=0$  or $\frac 1 2 y^2=-2x^2$

Trying $x=-1$,  we get the first equation simplifies to
$$0=-(1-4-y^2)$$
so $$y^2=-3$$,  no solution.  The other case, multiplying by 2 to clear the fractions, we get

$$y^2=-4x^2$$
Since $y^2\geq 0$ and $-4x^2\leq 0$,  we get they are both 0, so you have only the trivial solution